# Errors running claymore on linux

Tags: ether, linux, claymore

My claymore miner running on my Linux Mint mining rig was running fine but now this is happening?

```
ETH: Stratum - Connected (eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999)
ETH: Authorized
Setting DAG epoch #115...
server: bind failed with error: 98 (check -mport option value), next attempt in 20sec...
Setting DAG epoch #115 for GPU #0
Create GPU buffer for GPU #0
OpenCL error - cannot allocate big buffer for DAG. Check readme.txt for possible solutions.
Setting DAG epoch #115 for GPU #0
GPU 0, OpenCL error -38 - cannot write buffer for DAG
ETH: 04/03/17-20:23:32 - New job from eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "-mport 0" to the effected miner as an option in the miner.sh file worked for me.